# BO2 "Fresh Start"

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Does using "fresh start" in BO2 affect your "league best" or league play in general?

Because, I observed, that people reset their stats and their "league best" would still be the same.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research i'm still not able to provide a flawless answer but i think i'm pretty close.

Performing a 'Fresh start' in black ops 2 resets you of every act you have ever done in multiplayer. This means you lose all your: weapons, camo's, call-cards, attachments etc. This also means that you lose your k/d stats in regular multiplayer. I say regular multiplayer since i couldn't find any proof or evidence or even people complaining about the fact that they lost their league standings. A fresh start is often described as starting over when you want to improve your k/d.

I pulled the following comments from Call of duty forums about the matter:

> I would guess no, it wouldnt affect your league status, since the
>   stats in league are separate from normal stats.

and

> I was wishing it would, but oddly enough, they consider league play
>   "outside" of the normal MP just like Zombies - neither are effected by
>   a fresh start

and

> league play doesnt get reset from league play. reseting isnt worth it
>   unless you are one of those people that ABSOLUTELY have to.